# Constructing a json request in httparty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rest, httparty

I am trying to replicate the following curl request using Httparty with no success. I was wondering how best to construct the nested json with httparty. Any examples of nest queries I have seen have been no help. I am receiving a 500 error from the API I am trying to access. Any help appreciated

```
curl https://api.relateiq.com/v2/contacts
-X POST
-u [API Key]:[API Secret]
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'
-H 'Accept: application/json'
-d '{
    "properties" : {
        "name" : [
            {
                "value" : "James McSales"
            }
        ],
        "email" : [
            {
                "value" : "james.mcsales@relateiq.com"
            },
            {
                "value" : "jimmy@personal.com"
            }
        ],
        "phone" : [
            {
                "value" : "(888) 555-1234"
            },
            {
                "value" : "(888) 555-0000"
            }
        ],
        "address": [
            {
                "value": "123 Main St, USA"
            }
        ],
        "company": [
            {
                "value": "RelateIQ"
            }
        ],
        "title": [
            {
                "value": "Noob"
            }
        ]
    }
}'
```

This is what a shortened version my httparty request looks like,

```
HTTParty.post(
    "https://api.relateiq.com/v2/contacts",
:body => {
        :properties => {
    :name => [{:value => "Falcao Test"}],
    :email => [{:value => "FalcaoTest@monaco.fr"}]
    }
    },
    :basic_auth => auth,
:options => { :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' } }
)
```

and the request is like so

https://api.relateiq.com/v2/contacts>, @options={:limit=>5, :assume_utf16_is_big_endian=>true, :default_params=>{}, :follow_redirects=>true, :parser=>HTTParty::Parser, :connection_adapter=>HTTParty::ConnectionAdapter, :body=>{:properties=>{:name=>[{:value=>"Falcao Test"}], :email=>[{:value=>"FalcaoTest@monaco.fr"}]}}, :basic_auth=>{:username=>"5400a0b7e4b052e888539fb7", :password=>"WNyLKfLZ9wK1hEyY6249VQKQ4zS"}, :options=>{:headers=>{"Content-Type"=>"application/json"}}}, @last_uri=#https://api.relateiq.com/v2/contacts>, @raw_request=#, @last_response=#>

I have used httparty before but not with a structure which contains nesting with `[]` before. That is what is confusing me

Comment: Welcome on SO. Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Did you call `to_json` on the body ? i don't think httparty knows that it needs to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could never get this structure replicated with HTTParty, that has never happened before. I ended up having to use curb and an escaped json string

Answer (score 0):

Your json is different.

Your curl example does

```
    "name" : [
        {
            "value" : "James McSales"
        }
    ],
```

ie the value for the key "name" is an array containing one object (with key value)

Your httparty code has

```
 :name => {:value => "Falcao Test"}
```

so the value for the key "name" is not an array any more

To match the original example it should be

```
 :name => [{:value => "Falcao Test}]
```

Comment: I have gone through many attempts at this none of which are working. The above example is just one. Could you tell me how to represent the the curl example using httparty?

Comment: I added an example. You're also submitting different data (eg your httparty version has no company) - if that data was mandatory that might be a problem

Comment: Yeah I shortened it for brevity. The only mandatory field is email. I have updated the question and request details to now take account of your point. However I still receive the same 500 error